# 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I need help, i don't understand this
My code:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pywinauto import Application, findwindows, WindowSpecification


#Iniciando o chromedriver

pasta_atual = os.getcwd()
service = Service("./chromedriver.exe")
chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': 'true'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

An error:

```
driver.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'
```

I'm trying to change google preferences using prefs, so that I can choose the download directory, but I don't know why, I can't find the error in the code

I'm utilizing Selenium4

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation on [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chromium/selenium.webdriver.chromium.options.html), it looks like you should add the option to your `chrome_options` instead of your `driver`.

Changing your code from

```
chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': 'true'}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

to

```
chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': 'true'}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
```

should do the trick !

Answer (score 0):

I'm change code to import time

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pywinauto import Application, findwindows, WindowSpecification


#Iniciando o chromedriver
pasta_atual = os.getcwd()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = ChromeService(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

#Configurando preferencias do navegador
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'download.prompt_for_download': True})
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

But prefs dont works, why?